# output multi if statements to mail

Tags: sh

Using sh on linux I am looking to output the results from multiple if statements to a mail message.

```
#snap server1
running=`ps -U server1 | wc -l`
if [ $running -eq 1 ]; then
        /root/zfsnap/zfSnap.sh -v -a 30d tank/server1
fi

#snap server2
running=`ps -U server2 | wc -l`
if [ $running -eq 1 ]; then
        /root/zfsnap/zfSnap.sh -v -a 30d tank/server2
fi

sleep 3 && echo "results of script" | mail -s "snapshot status" administrator@domain.local

## current output is 
[root@backupserver ~]# ./backup_script_daily.sh
/sbin/zfs snapshot  tank/server1@2013-08-26_12.28.22--30d ... DONE
/sbin/zfs snapshot  tank/server2@2013-08-26_12.28.22--30d ... DONE
```

I'm not really sure how to do this for multiple if statements. I've seen many discussions on individual if statements.  I actually have about 8 more (user/servers) in this script.  My scripting experience for years has been very low level :).  Would it be better to use something like Perl

```
put servers into array
for each server in array
run command > to text file
end and mail(textfile)
```

I appreciate any suggestions or ideas and I apologize for any issues with the post. This is my first one.

Kind Regards,

~Jon R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose all commands whose output you want to capture in a `{ }` block and pipe the whole thing into the `mail` command, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    for server in server{1..2}; do
        if (( $(pgrep -U "${server}" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) > 0 )); then
            /root/zfsnap/zfSnap.sh -v -a 30d "tank/${server}"
        fi
    done
} | mail -s "snapshot status" administrator@domain.local
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it.  Appreciate the response!

Comment: I did have to add a printf with a newline inside the if statement to make the mail a bit more readable :)

Comment: I thought the printf "textgoeshere\n" would work but only in the shell.  Seems once it gets into the email the newlines get striped :(

Comment: Check the sourcecode of the mail once it is delivered, if you print newlines via `echo`/`printf` they should be there.